# How to preserve content of variable after pipe

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
cat $file
n=$(cat $file | wc -l)
cat $file
```

I use it like that `cat some_file.txt | myScript.sh`
the first `cat` outputs the content of the file while the second doesn't.
How can I preserve the content of the variable after the pipe?

Comment: You have too many cats together in the same bag.

Comment: and are they arguing with each other?

Comment: your script uses the first argument `$1` but I don't see where you're passing a parameter to the script (rather catting some_file.txt to the script's stdin)

Comment: So how should  this behave? Should `file` store the whole content of the file in the first line? and if not, why is the first cat working like that

Comment: Indeed - I don't think the problem is what you think it is. Are you hoping for the contents of `some_file.txt` to be given to `myScript.sh` as parameters? Or for `$file` to contain the contents of `some_file.txt`? Neither of those is going to happen. Perhaps you can tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want `$file` to have the content of the file, in which case I should invoke the script like `./myScipt.sh some_file.txt`. But I am curious, why the way I do it I get to see the content of the file after the first cat

Comment: To try to understand why you're seeing behaviour from the first `cat` which looks similar to what you want, try running `cat` (no parameters) from the command line. Enter some text on the keyboard - you'll see it echoed back to you.

Comment: Okay, @terdon explained why I was seeing the results, I was just a bit confused but I should have figured out, thnx

Comment: Rule of thumb: Never use variables in shell scripts without `""` surrounding them – unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think it's doing. The `$1` is the first parameter you pass to the script but you're not actually passing any. This means that `cat $file` actually becomes `cat` alone. When not given any argument, `cat` will just print its input:

```
$ echo "foo" | cat
foo
```

So, the first `cat` prints out the input, the contents of the file. The second has no input since it all has been taken by the first, so it does nothing. What you want to do is something like:

```
myscript.sh file
```

That will print out the contents of the file twice and also save the output of `cat $file |wc` in the variable `n`.

---

If what you want is to save the contents of the file in `$file`, try:

```
file="$(cat < "$1")"
```

And run the script with the file name as an argument:

```
script.sh file
```